# How we can perform --pipe cli command via the node redis client for large set of SET commands (25M +)

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis, redis-cluster

I am working on a disaster recovery script that involves bulk imports of more than 25 million records. To accomplish this, I have prepared a `data.txt` file and tested it on macOS using the `redis-cli` command.

I am following the solution explained in the Redis documentation on bulk loading, which can be found at https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/bulk-loading/.

The command I used for bulk loading is `cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe`

Now, I want to implement this command in my Node.js code (specifically in AWS Lambda), using the redis package. However, I have been unable to find a way to achieve this functionality using the Redis Node.js client provided by the redis npm package.

I would appreciate any assistance in finding a solution for executing the bulk loading functionality described above using the redis Node.js package, which can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a pipeline in Node Redis in a couple of ways.  Firstly, wrap everything you want to do in the pipeline in `Promise.all`:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();
await client.connect();

await Promise.all([
  client.set('Tm9kZSBSZWRpcw==', 'users:1'),
  client.sAdd('users:1:tokens', 'Tm9kZSBSZWRpcw==')
]);

await client.disconnect();
```

Alternatively you can use `multi` to start a transaction like sequence, then use `execAsPipeline()` to send all the commands to the Redis server at once.

Example:

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();
await client.connect();

const pipeline = client.multi();

pipeline.set('a', 'b');
pipeline.set('b', 'd');
pipeline.set('c', 'e');

await pipeline.execAsPipeline();

await client.disconnect();
```

You might also want to take a look at the RIOT tool for bulk data moves in and out of Redis https://github.com/redis-developer/riot

Comment: Yes we can use the above approach but this are not the actual solution that redis provide  for bulk insert. If we try this for 25M records (around 8GB) they will take a higher memory as well as a higher execution time. But I did POC around the `--pipe` with Redis protocol and it is more optimized and took very less time. But I did not find any document how we can achieve this via the Node.js

Comment: So are you looking for something in Node that will take a data file and convert it to the Redis protocol strings that can then be piped into the `redis-cli` command.  Or are you looking to invoke `redis-cli --pipe` from Node using `exec()` or similar?  I'm a little congused what node's role is here.

Comment: looking to invoke `redis-cli --pipe` from Node using `exec()` or similar in AWS lambda. I have data.txt file ready